# Joomla 3 modules breaking within admin - "Fatal error: Allowed memory size exhausted "

Tags: memory, joomla

After moving a client's site live, from our server to theirs, I found that I get the following error whenever you try to open ANY module to make changes to it:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 104857600 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 42949672941 bytes) in /home/ceipacer/public_html/administrator/components/com_modules/views/module/tmpl/edit_assignment.php on line 91

That line in the code reads: `echo str_repeat('</li></ul>', $prevlevel - $link->level);`

After some research, I found that a lot of people have had this problem and solved it by creating a php.ini file with a line to increase the filesize, or adding code to the top of the /index.php and /administrator/index.php files. Here is what I've tried so far:

php.ini:

```
register_globals = Off
upload_max_filesize = 40M
post_max_size = 40M
memory_limit = 40M
upload_tmp_dir = 40M
max_execution_time = 180
```

/index.php and /administrator/index.php:

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit','40M');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The error message in your question states that the memory limit is already set at `104857600 bytes` or 104.8576 MB so the 'php.ini' setting you added will only make this worse.
2. The second part of the message is saying that PHP `tried to allocate 42949672941 bytes` this is a fairly big number, in simpler terms it is 42.949672941 GB.
3. The only setting that could affect this error message is `memory_limit` the rest of them shouldn't be of consideration if all you're doing is opening a module to edit it.

Given the relatively massive numbers in the error message I think there is a serious issue on their server or with the database. I would start by looking through the servers and PHP's error logs.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I will take a look through the logs and if there is anything strange I will share.